# typo3 text and media position and picture width has no effect

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In my typo3 6.2.31 page the text and media content doesn't work properly.

Changing the width and position of a picture has absolute no effect.

[image]

what could be the problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Text & Media" ? that sound like FSC (Fluid Styled Content) and that was not very elaborated for 6.2.
you might need to evaluate those setings in the templates / partials for your CEs (Content elements).

In general: all those input fields **could** be evaluated in the rendering of an CE. maybe someone wanted an simple rendering with less option for editors to mess around with the design. So he ignores those inputs (but forgot to disable the display in BE for editors).

Have alook whether you use CSC or FSC.
With CSC the rendering is done in typoscript.
With FSC the rendering is done in fluid templates. Look for all pathes where templates and partials are (re)defined.

---

add on:
For CSC the rendering is defined in typoscript. use the TSOB (TyposcriptObjectbrowser) to identify the involved parts. You can start with `tt_content.textpic` in that COA you will find `.10`and `.20`.
`.10` renders the header, `.20` renders the body of the CE.
Follow the definition and look what fields are used. You might compare an *empty* installation with yours to see mdifications to the default rendering.

Comment: I don't use Fluid Styled Content there. Do you have some hints what I have to looking for?

Comment: I enhanced my answer

Answer (score 1):

First you should look where the image are rendered and if these fields are used, too. Maybe the image dimensions are hardcoded in your typoscript.